# Why does ditto send errors to stdout and output to stderr?

Tags: bash, macos

Maybe I'm missing something, but when I type do a verbose ditto command (`ditto [-v] [-V] 2>>some.log`), it will send regular output to `stderr`. Therefore, my `some.log` file will be filled with entries like `copying file ...`.

This doesn't make logical sense to me, but it's what the manual says as well:

> ```
> -V            Print a line of output to stderr for every file, symbolic
>               link, and device copied.
> ```

I haven't verified this, but I assume that actual I/O errors are sent to `stdout`. My original want was to display regular output, but log all errors. So assuming that errors are sent to `stdout`, then this problem isn't really much of a problem - it's just that the semantics don't make sense to me.

So, this should give me the correct outputs:

```
ditto -V /some/path/ /some/other/path 1>>some.log
```

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `ditto` sends both error messages and verbose status messages to stderr.  The reason is that if it's in `-c` (create archive) mode, and the destination file was specified as `-`, it writes the archive to stdout.  Having status messages mixed in with the archive would be very very bad. BTW, `tar -v` does the same thing, for the same reason.

Comment: I tried this before though: `ditto -V /some/path/ /some/other/path 2>>some.log` and in my terminal I got output saying:
I/O Error [...], but in my log, I got all the copying, etc. So what's the best way to get the log of errors - is it possible at all?

Comment: When I tried using `ditto` to copy a file I don't have read access to, it printed the error to stderr.  Are you sure that I/O Error message was coming from `ditto`?

Comment: Perhaps not? I just tried after removing read access, and it was went to stderr; however, I was attempting this on a system with a bad harddrive earlier, and the I/O error printed to stdout (perhaps not by ditto).